# How to declare object's properties that are methods for getting HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is declaring an object like the `inputs` below a good practice?

I am worried about the fact that the DOM would have to be searched every time object's property is called, `inputs.voucher` for example.

If not, how do I do this otherwise?

```
var inputs = {
     bu: document.getElementById("InputKeys_BUSINESS_UNIT"),
     voucher: document.getElementById("InputKeys_VOUCHER"),
     invoice: document.getElementById("InputKeys_INVOICE_ID"),
     vendor_id: document.getElementById("InputKeys_VENDOR_ID"),
     requester: document.getElementById("InputKeys_BUSINESS_UNIT"),
     vendor_name: document.getElementById("InputKeys_BUSINESS_UNIT")
};
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Where is the function named "documentGetElementById()" defined, Cause I ain't seeing no function defined as such?

Comment: I regularly do this when I’m writing small amounts of pure JS, but I make the declaration at the beginning of whatever function I’m writing. It’s not so much for performance, as it is to provide simple (and readable) access to the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it on this way! This code is absolutely correct code. But I personally would short your code like follows:

```
function $(id){return document.getElementById(id)}

var inputs =
{
     bu: $("InputKeys_BUSINESS_UNIT"),
     voucher: $("InputKeys_VOUCHER"),
     invoice: $("InputKeys_INVOICE_ID"),
     vendor_id: $("InputKeys_VENDOR_ID"),
     requester: $("InputKeys_BUSINESS_UNIT"),
     vendor_name: $("InputKeys_BUSINESS_UNIT")
};
```

because the server and the clients will have less to work and you will save resources.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's less appealing to look at but a little memoization can go a long way. You could do the following:

```js
var getById = (function() {
    var cache = {};
    return function getById(id) {
        if (cache[id]) { return cache[id]; }
        
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        cache[id] = el;
        return el;
    }
})();

var inputs = {
    bu: getById("InputKeys_BUSINESS_UNIT"),
    voucher: getById("InputKeys_VOUCHER"),
    invoice: getById("InputKeys_INVOICE_ID"),
    vendor_id: getById("InputKeys_VENDOR_ID"),
    requester: getById("InputKeys_BUSINESS_UNIT"),
    vendor_name: getById("InputKeys_BUSINESS_UNIT"),
};
```

The method `getById` will either return the element from the page and cache it, or if it finds it in the cache return the cached version.

### Some issues

If you're changing the page contents and not reloading the page, you need a mechanism that expires that cache or you'll get stale (wrong) elements. This is especially true in an SPA.

### A possible solution

Ideally this would be much more elegant with new ES modules, but here's a direction you can take if you want to keep it all together:

```js
var getById = (function() {
    var cache = {};
    var api = {
        clear: function clear() { cache = {}; }
    };

    return function getById(id) {
        if (!arguments.length) { return api; }

        if (cache[id]) { return cache[id]; }
        
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        cache[id] = el;
        return el;
    }
})();

// to clear you would do
getById().clear();
```

These are just ideas. You may want to also consider that this caching might already be done by the browser and this might be a premature optimization. I would consider this sort of thing only an issue if you're seeing a slowdown.

Comment: It is absolutely unnecessary to have so much objects and to write so much code!